# Get Div Value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, xslt

I have a code like this

```
<p class="shownote">
Text value
<a href="#" class="show">
textvalues</a>
<input class="editnotesbox" style="display:none"></input>  
<a href="#" class="editnote">Edit</a>
<a href="#" class="deletenote">Delete</a>
<div class="hidennote" style="display: none;">
Text value
</div>
</p>
```

and I want to get the div  hidennote class value in jquery variable.I try Jquery like this.

```
 $('.show').live('click', function (event) {

        $(this).parent('.shownote').find('.editnotesbox').show();
         var getnote = $(this).closest('.hidennote').text;
        $('.editnotesbox').val(getnote);
        $(this).hide();

    });
```

but can't get the value.How can i achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to place a `<div>` element inside a `<p>` in the DOM because the opening `<div>` tag will automatically close the `<p>` element.

An authoritative place to look for allowed containment relations is the HTML spec. See, [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#inline) at HTML content models. It specifies which elements are block elements and which are inline.

So replace the div with `<span>` and Try:  [Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XPSPU/2/)

```
$(".shownote").on('click', '.show', function (event) {
   var shownote = $(this).parent();
   shownote.find('.editnotesbox').show();
   var getnote = shownote.find('.hidennote').text();
   $('.editnotesbox').val(getnote);
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Also avoid `.live()` which is deprecated as of jQuery 1.9, use `.on()`

Comment: No error showing..but i put alert(getnote),it did't show any values in getnote

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.hidennote').text()
```

It of course returns the div's text, as div doesn't have a value.

Based on you update:

```
$('.show').live('click', function (event) {
    $shownote = $(this).parent();
    $shownote.find('.editnotesbox').show();
    var getnote = $shownote.find('.hidennote').text();
    $('.editnotesbox').val(getnote);
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Just be aware that `live` was deleted in 1.9 in deprecated in 1.7.

Comment: @Arun, I've no idea how did you managed to get that error. wait, did you write the selector between two strings? it should be `'div.hidennote'` not `div.hidennote`.